# Help with VF page and Querying OpportunityLineItems

Tags: soql, opportunity-lineitem, product

I am doing some work for a client and they have asked if I could make a "child/parent" relationship between OpportunityLineItem (OLI) records.

I have been told by someone they have seen it done before and it has been done by adding a lookup to the Product2 to another Product2 record.

The client then wants the OLI parents to be displayed on a page (I will be using apex:repeat for this due to the table style), they they want a nested table within this table where they display the child OLI's. I have been able to work the VF side so far and it all looks good.

However I have been racking your brains trying to work out how to do this... but I just can not get it to work D: does anyone have any ideas or pointers?

I just need the most basic set of fields from the OLI's to display, it's literally just the Name, Quantity, Discount, ListPrice, UnitPrice and TotalPrice from both the parent and child.

****UPDATE****
I am displaying the Opp at the top of a VF page, then under that I need to display a table of all of the Parent/"Master" OLI's and in each OLD row, I need to display the Child/"Extra" OLI's so it will be kind of like this:

```
-------- Opp Info --------
| Name        Stage      |
--------------------------
|  OLI 1 Master Details  |
|                        |
|  --------------------- |
|  |OLI 1 Child Details| |
|  --------------------- |
--------------------------
|  OLI 2 Master Details  |
|                        |
|  --------------------- |
|  |OLI 2 Child Details| |
|  --------------------- |
--------------------------
```

Comment: OLI is always in the context of an Opportunity, yet I see no mention of Opportunity in your question. Are you creating this in the context of a single Opportunity where you want to query the related OLIs with their Product2Ids?

Comment: @crmprogdev Yeah sorry... I'll update the Q now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this out in quite a long winded way, but it seems to be displaying okay so far...

Method:

```
Map<OpportunityLineItem, List<OpportunityLineItem>> masterToExtraMap = new Map<OpportunityLineItem, List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
List<OpportunityLineItem> liList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
liList = [SELECT Id, Name, Quantity, ListPrice, Description, ProductCode, TotalPrice
          FROM OpportunityLineItem
          WHERE OpportunityId =: opp.Id
          AND Product2.RecordType.Name =: 'Master'];

for(OpportunityLineItem oli : liList){
    List<OpportunityLineItem> extraLi = new List<OpportunityLineItem>([SELECT Id, Name, Quantity, ListPrice, Description, ProductCode, TotalPrice
                                                                       FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                                                       WHERE Product2.Master_Product__c =: oli.Product2Id
                                                                       AND Product2.RecordType.Name =: 'Extra']);
    masterToExtraMap.put(oli, extraLi);
}

oppLineItems = masterToExtraMap;
```

Then I am using apex:repeat nested in an apex:outputPanel which is surrounded in an apex:repeat again....

As I said it's long winded but seems to work okay :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a field that shows the child relationship between the Parent OLI, I'm not entirely certain how you can accomplish what you're asking other than perhaps by sorting the returned records by `CreatedDate` and `Product2Id`. Assuming you have the `Actual OppId`, I'd expect the query to look something like this:

```
list<OpportunityLineItem>OLI = [SELECT ID, Name, Quantity, ListPrice, UnitPrice, 
  TotalPrice, Product2ID, CreatedDate OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem 
  WHERE OpportunityId =: ActualOpp.Id ORDER BY Product2ID ];
```

You should be able to do an `ORDER BY` on this without needing to make it an `AggregateResult`. Optionally, you could also add the `CreatedDate` after the `Product2Id` as a secondary sort if you don't have a field that allows you to generate the parent-child relationship you're looking for. I've assumed they'd have the same `Product2Id`, but I could be wrong on that as only you would know. Whatever the criteria is, use it in your Order By clause, then put the results in a wrapper class.

Comment: thanks for this, I have tried with a basic query this way and yeah I do know the Opp Id, the issue is I need to actually display the Child/"Extra" OLI's in a nested table, so if there are 10 extras again 1 Parent/"Master" OLI then these all need to display below the Parent... which is the pain in the butt... I spoke to the person again in passing and they categorically said there is a way which is annoying as I REALLY can't work this out and it's stressing me out -_-

Comment: You presumably have a couple of options here. If you add the 2nd OrderBy clause so that it's `ORDER BY Product2ID, CreatedDate`, any children would follow the parent since `CreatedDate` is a `DateTime` (of OLI) and would thus represent a child record since the default is ascending order. I'm having difficulty seeing where an aggregateResult query using a `Group By` would do anything for you.